# nodejs api for philips hue power consumption

Tags: node.js, computation, energy, philips-hue

Is there a way we can compute the energy/power consumption of the Philips hue? 
Any nodejs api which I can use to showcase the same. I searched in the internet, I did not find any resource which has information about computing the energy/power consumption.

Comment: please read [ask] before asking, welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a public nor private api for Philips hue bulbs. The [bridge drains constant power of 1.6W](http://www.everyhue.com/vanilla/discussion/64/power-consumption-for-the-bridge-unit), each bulb when on [drains 5W, and 0.4W](http://greenmonk.net/2014/02/20/internet-things-connected-philips-hue-bulbs-review/) when off. You can calculate the drain yourself using these metrics.